# How do I change fonts and add colors in Contacts?

Tags: contacts.app

I just discovered how to change fonts and add colors to Notes by using command T.  How can I change fonts and add colors to Contacts?  (Conmmand T does not work for Contacts).

Answer (score 1):

The Contacts app uses the system font. To change font or font size in Contacts.app, you must change it for your whole system. There is a way to change the system font from San Francisco font to Lucida Grande font which may be more appealing to you. There is a small app that lets you pick between San Francisco and Lucida Grande fonts for your system. This [web page](http://osxdaily.com/2017/11/19/change-macos-high-sierra-system-font-lucida-grande/) provides a link to the application or you can go straight to it [here](https://github.com/LumingYin/macOSLucidaGrande).

Comment: And to expand a bit there is no supported, built-in way to change fonts/colors of the fields or text within the Address Book.app. The closest I have ever come to this is to add an emoji or two after the company or person's last name. But changing the system font changes *EVERY* app that uses the system font on the Mac. Not something I would generally recommend.